# Applying id to body in jade

Tags: pug

I am pretty confused on how to add an id to the body tag in jade

so far I have tried

```
   block body#idname
```

and

```
block body(id='idname')
```

What is the proper way to add an id to the body tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both syntaxes are correct. 
`body#idname` is just a shorthand for `body(id="idname")`.

However, I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve with `block body`.

A `block` is not an HTML element. It's used to create sections, for templating purposes. Therefore, its name is just an identifier, not an HTML tagname.

You can read more about it [here](http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/).